# Escape nested template in ansible/jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In ansible/jinja2 one needs to escape double braces: `{{.Foo}}` should be `{{'{{'}}.Foo{{'}}'}}`.

But how do I escape a nested template? e.g.

```yaml
- name: Find running containers on swarm/non-swarm hosts
  shell: "{{item}}"                                        # <------ problem here
  loop:
    - { "docker stack ls --format '{{'{{'}}.Name{{'}}'}}'" }
    - { "docker ps -a    --format '{{'{{'}}.Names{{'}}'}}'" }
  register: result
```

The problem is the loop item undergoes templating again, in the `shell:` line.

Error:

> ...template error while templating string: unexpected '.'

Answer (score 1):

You will want the [`{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping) blocks in jinja, although be aware that your use of `{{ item }}` like that makes you subject to [ansible's recursive jinja evaluation](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/4638#issuecomment-26928000), which is what I suspect is tripping you up even right now with your `{{ {{ }}` business

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |
      {% raw %}
      docker stack ls --format '{{.Name}}'
      docker ps -a    --format '{{.Names}}'
      {% endraw %}
```

Although you might also be happier using [the actual ansible module designed for working with docker](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/general/docker_container_module.html)

Comment: Thanks. Yes that recursive behavior is what I'm referring to. The raw/endraw trick e.g. `{%raw%}item.shell{%endraw%}` doesn't work. Is there no way around that other than to redesign my task?

Comment: It seems that sending it through one level of indirection bypasses the recursion (I've seen that in effect merely by prefixing the variable name with `vars.` but that specific trick doesn't work for `item`): `- shell: echo {{ lookup("vars", "item") }}` -- can you see if that works for your case?

Answer (score 1):

Due to templating of `item` which contains the `{{` Jinja delimiters escaping them is complex. As @mdaniel suggested, it might be simpler to use an ansible module designed to working with docker. One slightly hacky way to make Jinja delimiters to be ignored is to use the concat operation with the `item` *inside* a Jinja context.

Something like this:

```yaml
  tasks:
    - shell: "{{ 'docker ' ~ item.cmd ~ ' --format ' ~ '\"' ~ '{{ ' ~ item.pattern ~ ' ' ~ '}}' ~ '\"' }}"
      register: docker_cmd
      loop:
        - cmd: 'ps -a'
          pattern: '.Names'
        - cmd: 'stack ls'
          pattern: '.Name'
```

It does look very cryptic, but seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. I actually did something very similar to this. I was hoping there ware a non hacky way to do it, but this is the only approach that actually works for me.